# Synchronous AJAX (broken promises)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to coax JavaScript into *synchronous* behaviour, but I've so far failed.

I've tried 30 or more different methods, and here is the latest attempt, based on another answer, here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/630530):

```
function fnc () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "libraries/resources/data.json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            ...
            objSomething = {
                ...
            };
    },
        error: function () {}
    });
}
fnc().then(function(objSomething) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){ initialize(objSomething); });
}).catch(function(objSomething) {
    ...
});
```

However, I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'fnc().then')

Most of the methods I've tried have resulted in similar errors.

As for the Google Maps code, it does work (although not always, due to the asynchronous nature of the code execution).

It's worth noting that while I'm able to write complex code from scratch, when it comes to the underlying mechanics, I'm not that proficient.

I'm using jQuery 2.2.2, via the Google API CDN.

Comment: Your `fnc` function doesn't return anything, so you can't do `fnc().then()`...

Comment: @Cristy, based on the examples I've tried, some had a return statement, some didn't. I've tried a return statement and it doesn't work. I'd appreciate an example of what — in your opinion — should work.

Comment: @WayneSmallman "It doesn't work" doesn't provide enough information to diagnose. If a function doesn't return anything, you can't call anything on its return value--if there's an example suggestion you can, that example is incorrect.

Comment: You should take a look over basic `JavaScript` function calls and `async` functions. After that you should be able to solve your issue pretty quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution you are looking for.

```
   function fnc () {
        var dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "libraries/resources/data.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                ...
                objSomething = {
                    ...
                };
             dfd.resolve(objSomething);
        },
            error: function (error) { dfd.reject(error); }
        });

        return dfd.promise();
    }

    $.when(fnc()).then(function(objSomething) {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function(){ 
           initialize(objSomething); 
        });
     }, function(error){
       //Handle Error
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$.ajax` function you can use the `then` function. Refer the following link:

```
http://wildermuth.com/2013/8/3/JavaScript_Promises
```